# Run two Angular CLI tasks after each other, with --watch

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have two tasks, that need to run after each other:

```
ng build <library-name> && ng serve
```

I want to have file change watching on the `<libary-name>`, so I add this:

```
ng build <library-name> --watch && ng serve
```

This is obviously not working, as the watch will never finish, so the ng serve will never get called.

```
ng build <library-name> --watch & ng serve
```

this solution is also not good, as the ng serve starts before the ng build finishes.

Is there any way, to capture the *Compilation complete* message from the first ng build, and **then** let file watcher run? Is there any way to just start the watcher maybe like this:

```
ng build <library-name> && --watch-the-libary-please & ng serve
```

?

Comment: You can only let them execute one after the other if you don't `--watch` the first one. The alternative is to simply execute the build commands in separate sessions.

Comment: Yeah, this is our workaround now, but I hope that there is a nicer solution.

Comment: Write a bash script to do that. You can even create custom service if this needs to be triggered periodically.

Comment: @ForestG Could you look at my solution, does it work for you? It will rebuild and serve after any changes made to lib. So now you don't need --wach flag because script is guarding changes. Or maybe I've made it overcomplicated. Anyways I'd like know what you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use npm package [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently), which allows running multiple commands in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem: I need to start up the second process  after the first build is finished.

Comment: you can run `ng build && concurrently "ng build --watch" "ng serve"`.

Comment: Yeah, this solution works, however you can also do it without it: this is basically the same as `ng build tariff-lib && (ng build tariff-lib --watch & ng serve)`

Comment: Hmmm... this answer is "good enough", but doesn't actually do what the OP asked. This runs them concurrently (obv) not sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I might have found a solution for you. I have written simple Python script which will check whether directory (in this case your library) has been changed by calculating its sha1sum. If it's in fact changed then it will run your commands for **ng build** and **ng serve**

```python
import time
import os
from checksumdir import dirhash

directory = '/YOUR/PATH/TO/LIBRARY'
initial_sha1 = dirhash(directory, 'sha1')

modified = False

while modified is False:
    current_sha1 = dirhash(directory, 'sha1')
    if initial_sha1 != current_sha1:
        print("Files has been hanged")
        os.system('ng build <libary-name>')
        os.system('ng serve')
        modified = True
    else:
        time.sleep(10)
```

If you want to run this indefinitely instead of changing flag `modified` to True change value of initials sha to current `initial_sha1 = current_sha1` and kill program when you want.

You might need to install this package:

```
pip install checksumdir
```

This works under Python 2.7 and 3.X (You might need to install checksumdir with pip3 for that)

#### Edit

You might need to exec this script under a directory in which you build your app, or add before **ng buld**

```python
os.system('cd /PATH/WHERE/YOU/BUILD')
```

Comment: thank you, but using python just for this is an overkill. Also, I belive that this script does re-run ng serve every time without stopping the previous one?

Comment: @ForestG Yep it does not re-run ng serve, but this could be easily implemented. I just didn't think through at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I could come out with a solution. So, leaving it here.

Having the following scripts, `npm start` will start both `ng build my-lib` and `ng build serve` in parallel, and whichever you make a change in `my-app` or `my-lib`, it will trigger the build.

The steps to be executed are:

1. Delete the directory at my library out path `dist-lib`
2. start building my-lib with `--watch` option
3. run `wait-for-lib.js` to wait until the my-lib output directory is created
4. start dev server for `my-app`

package.json

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all clean:lib --parallel start:**",
    "start:app": "node ./scripts/wait-for-lib.js && ng serve",
    "start:lib": "ng build my-lib --watch",
    "clean:lib": "shx rm -rf ./dist-lib"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "shx": "^0.3.3"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```js
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist"
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    },
    "my-lib": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-lib"
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "defaultProject": "my-app"
}
```

./scripts/wait-for-lib.js

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const pathToMyLib = './dist-lib/my-lib';

function waitFor(path) {
    console.log(`Waiting for ${path} is created...`);
    if (!fs.existsSync(path))
        setTimeout(() => waitFor(path), 1000);
}

waitFor(pathToMyLib);
```